# Speed up HTTP Post Speed

Tags: c#, optimization, http-post

I am writing an application to send text messages through HTTP posts to a Slooce Tech API. Because the application will have to send a high volume of text messages, I'm trying to optimize its speed.

The second piece of code below is the method that I am currently using to send the posts. I wrote the first piece of code and left out the `HTTPWebResponse` to try to make it faster.

The problem is that the new method is actually slower and rather than taking .25 seconds to execute, it takes a second or more and sometimes will get stuck.

Does anyone know why it would do that or any other tips for improving the speed of this application? I have added `Request.Proxy=null` and that speeds it up a little bit.

Thanks.

The modified code is:

```
    public void QuickSend()
    {
        XML = "<message id=\"" + lMessageID + "\"><partnerpassword>" + PartnerPassword + "</partnerpassword><content>" + sMessage + "</content></message>";
        URL = "http://sloocetech.net:****/spi-war/spi/" + PartnerID + "/" + sRecipient + "/" + Keyword + "/messages/mt";
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

        RequestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        Request.ContentLength = RequestBytes.Length;
        RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        RequestStream.Write(RequestBytes, 0, RequestBytes.Length);
        RequestStream.Close();
    }
```

And here is the original code:

```
    public XDocument SendSMS()
    {
        XML = "<message id=\""+ lMessageID +"\"><partnerpassword>" + PartnerPassword + "</partnerpassword><content>" + sMessage + "</content></message>";
        URL = "http://sloocetech.net:****/spi-war/spi/" + PartnerID + "/" + sRecipient + "/" + Keyword + "/messages/mt";
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

        RequestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        Request.ContentLength = RequestBytes.Length;
        RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        RequestStream.Write(RequestBytes, 0, RequestBytes.Length);
        RequestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse Resp = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
        oReader = new StreamReader(Resp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string backstr = oReader.ReadToEnd();

        oReader.Close();
        Resp.Close();

        Doc = XDocument.Parse(backstr);
        return Doc;
    }
```

Comment: You can't just leave out `Request.GetResponse()` since that's what actually sends the data you've built up in the web request.

Comment: You should put a `using` statement around your `GetResponse` code.  In doing so you can also omit your `Close` statement.

Comment: you should send multiple POSTs in parallel (i.e. async/TPL/ThreadPool/whatever...) to achieve a high throughput...

Comment: You may also contact owner of the service to check if it is OK to post high amount of data and what is the correct approach of doing so. Otherwise you may find that despite of all your effort to optimize your own code server simply throttle down handling of your responses.

Comment: The theoretical load to the number of requests that it can handle is 80 per second. I doubt I'm going to actually be able to touch that, but I want to get more than 5 per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd be very skeptical of any claims that you're going to see massive improvements because you're crafting your `HttpWebRequest` in a special way. The bottleneck on single threaded requests like yours is going to be network latency as well as the response time of the server. (Perhaps they're doing a lot of server-side processing before responding to your request).

You're making a blocking request, which means your CPU is doing nothing while it waits for a response.

If you want to multithread your application, you could do something like the following:

```
var tasks = new Task[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {    
        int messages_sent_by_one_task = 0;           
        while(messages_sent_by_one_task < 10)
        {
            QuickSend();
            messages_sent_by_one_task++;
        }
    });
}
while (tasks.Any(t => !t.IsCompleted)) { } //wait for tasks to complete
```

This will spawn 10 tasks that will each send 10 messages. If one response is taking a long time, the other 9 threads will continue chugging along happily.

I believe you could probably improve on this is you were to [incorporate asynchronous requests and HTTPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx), so each of your 10 threads never blocked. However, I don't feel qualified to give an example as I've never tried this.

You might be tempted to crank the number of threads up to some ungodly number, but avoid the temptation. The overhead of creating and managing threads will soon catch up with you. I don't know what the ideal number is, but you're welcome to experiment.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The service provider I'm working with can theoretically handle 80 HTTP requests per second. I will look into asynchronous requests and multithreading, because that seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm working on adding this now, I'll let you know if it works.